# Passing member function pointer as a template type

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, c++14

I don't understand why clang reject this code. I got it from my friend and it compiled on VisualStudio for him... I have TOT of clang.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template< typename Signature >
class Delegate;

template< typename Ret, typename Param >
class Delegate< Ret(Param) >
{
public:

   Ret operator()(Param&& p_param)
   {
      return m_ifunc(m_obj, std::forward< Param >(p_param));
   }

   template< typename ObjType, typename Ret(ObjType::*Method)(Param) >
   friend auto createDelegate(ObjType * const p_obj)
   {
      Delegate< Ret(Param) > del;
      del.m_obj = p_obj;
      del.m_ifunc = &ifunction< ObjType, Method >;
      return del;
   }

private:

   void * const m_obj = nullptr;
   Ret (*m_ifunc)(void*, Param&&) = nullptr;

   template< typename ObjType, typename Ret(ObjType::*Method)(Param) >
   static Ret ifunction(void * const p_obj, Param&& p_param)
   {
      ObjType * const obj = (ObjType * const) p_obj;
      return (obj->*Method)(std::forward< Param >(p_param));
   }
};

struct Test
{
   void test(int x)
   {
      std::cout << x << std::endl;
   }

};

int main()
{
   Test t;

   Delegate< void(int) > d = Delegate< void(int) >::createDelegate< Test, &Test::test >(&t);

   d(5);
}
```

This is the errors that I get Anybody understand what is going on? I have seen this way of specifying the template argument for function pointers I guess there is missing something do to the strictnees of clang.

```
main.cpp:17:41: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
   template< typename ObjType, typename Ret(ObjType::*Method)(Param) >
                                        ^
main.cpp:31:41: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
   template< typename ObjType, typename Ret(ObjType::*Method)(Param) >
                                        ^
main.cpp:52:53: error: no member named 'createDelegate' in 'Delegate<void (int)>'
   Delegate< void(int) > d = Delegate< void(int) >::createDelegate< Test, &Test::test >(&t);
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
main.cpp:52:69: error: 'Test' does not refer to a value
   Delegate< void(int) > d = Delegate< void(int) >::createDelegate< Test, &Test::test >(&t);
                                                                    ^
main.cpp:39:8: note: declared here
struct Test
       ^
main.cpp:52:82: error: definition or redeclaration of 'test' not allowed inside a function
   Delegate< void(int) > d = Delegate< void(int) >::createDelegate< Test, &Test::test >(&t);
                                                                           ~~~~~~^
main.cpp:52:86: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
   Delegate< void(int) > d = Delegate< void(int) >::createDelegate< Test, &Test::test >(&t);
                                                                                     ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, and I'm pretty certain it never compiled on VisualStudio in its current form. In any case, I can't get it to compile on VS2013. Here are the errors:

```
template< typename ObjType, typename Ret(ObjType::*Method)(Param) >
//                          ^^^^^^^^
// the member function pointer is a non-type template parameter, remove typename
friend auto createDelegate(ObjType * const p_obj)
// ^^^^
// you've declared this as a friend, but call it within main() as if it is a
// static member function, change 'friend' to 'static'


template< typename ObjType, typename Ret(ObjType::*Method)(Param) >
//                          ^^^^^^^^
// same as above, remove typename
static Ret ifunction(void * const p_obj, Param&& p_param)
```

The `m_obj` data member is a `const` pointer, yet you try to point it to a new object within `createDelegate`

```
void * const m_obj = nullptr;
//     ^^^^^
// remove the const
```

After making these changes

```
template< typename Signature >
class Delegate;

template< typename Ret, typename Param >
class Delegate< Ret(Param) >
{
public:

   Ret operator()(Param&& p_param)
   {
      return m_ifunc(m_obj, std::forward< Param >(p_param));
   }

   template< typename ObjType, Ret(ObjType::*Method)(Param) >
   static auto createDelegate(ObjType * const p_obj)
   {
      Delegate< Ret(Param) > del;
      del.m_obj = p_obj;
      del.m_ifunc = &ifunction< ObjType, Method >;
      return del;
   }

private:

   void * m_obj = nullptr;
   Ret (*m_ifunc)(void*, Param&&) = nullptr;

   template< typename ObjType, Ret(ObjType::*Method)(Param) >
   static Ret ifunction(void * const p_obj, Param&& p_param)
   {
      ObjType * const obj = (ObjType * const) p_obj;
      return (obj->*Method)(std::forward< Param >(p_param));
   }
};
```

Now the code compiles, and outputs `5`. [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf0ecdcf97771dc4)

---

An additional change is needed for this to compile on VS2013 (release version, don't know about the CTP). Since VS2013 doesn't implement C++14's return type deduction for ordinary functions, `createDelegate` needs to have the return type specified explicitly

```
template< typename ObjType, Ret(ObjType::*Method)(Param) >
static Delegate< Ret(Param) > createDelegate(ObjType * const p_obj)
{ /* ... */ }
```

---

Finally, just to make sure you're aware of the alternatives:

```
Test t;
auto d = std::bind(&Test::test, t, std::placeholders::_1);
d(5);    // prints 5
std::function<void(int)> d2 = std::bind(&Test::test, t, std::placeholders::_1);
d2(5);   // prints 5
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I made a mistake, the original code was not calling the function as a static function and clang was still complaining. [see this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cca0aefcc4a98ac3)

Comment: @monamimani I think the explanation I had earlier was wrong. The code you linked to in your comment [works as is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24ee043dc94d696e) on gcc-4.8, 4.9 and VS2013. So you might've found a clang bug.